# Powershell Automation Script Update AD Error the search filter is not recognized

Tags: powershell, csv, filter, active-directory

Im trying to achieve a simple Script to update my Active Directory in Windows and I keep getting the error: the Searchfilter is not recognized.

Heres the code:

```
$names = Import-Csv -Path c:\Users\aPohl\Documents\ad_user.csv

ForEach ($user in $names)
{
    $username  = $user.sAMAccountName
    $pager = $user.pager
    $found = Get-ADUser -Filter "sAMAccountName -eq '$username'" 
    if($found){$found|Set-ADUser -Replace @{pager = $pager} -Verbose}
}
```

Error Message:

```
Get-ADUser : Der Suchfilter wurde nicht erkannt
In Zeile:7 Zeichen:14
+     $found = Get-ADUser -Filter "sAMAccountName -eq '$username'"
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

And the CSV file is like this:

sAMAccountName, pager

TestUser, 23144121

What am I doing wrong? It seems like its working for other people cause I keep seeing the same Scripts whenever I Search in forums.

Comment: When you do `Write-Host "sAMAccountName -eq '$username'"`, what do you see?

Comment: sAMAccountName -eq ''" It seems like theres nothing but why does this happen?

Comment: Okay I just found the Error it doesnt read the Values from my CSV file I just hardcoded some values and it actually changed the AD User. Why does it not read from my CSV file any clue?

Comment: Have a close look at your csv file in notepad. What character is used to separate the fields? Probably not a comma, so you need to append `-Delimiter ';'` to the Import-Csv line if your csv uses the semi-colon `;` or set it to the character that is actually used.

Comment: Take-away: Always check your variable values. A good habit to get into is to print them to the console in the loop (e.g. `Write-Host`, or `Write-Debug` if you want to be able to switch off the output). This way you will catch these kinds of mistakes, and you get some sort of progress info while the loop runs.

Comment: Hello @Marcel,If my answer is helpful for you, you can upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you